# How do you continuously randomly change the colour of a Light Point with a Color Ramp?

Tags: blender

I am trying to create a scene that needs a light source that changes color.

The problem is that although I can get half way there by using a `Color Ramp` to input into an `Emission` which is then put into the `Light Output`.

[image: This is the current setup]

So far I have tried to plug the `Random Object Info` output into the `Color Ramp Fac` value to no avail. Do I need to use the driver `#noise.random()` in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass value node into Fac input of ColorRamp and then animate the value over time. To make it random use Noise Modifier on your animation chanel in Graph Editor.

[image: Blender nodes]

[image: Blender Graph editor]